# rename a file keeping first 10 characters intact

Tags: freebsd, rename

For example filenames are like this:

```
Order21039 Internal Document.doc
Order33920 New Order.doc
Order39307 Exam.doc
.
.
.
```

I want to keep the first ten characters and append another text like:

```
Order21039.test.doc
Order33920.test.doc
.
.
.
```

What is the best and easiest method for FreeBSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(?(#c10))*.doc' '$1.test.doc'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

You can change that to:

```
zmv -n '(Order<->)*.doc' '$1.test.doc'
```

To match on `Order<anydecimalnumber>` instead of just 10 characters.

With `perl` rename:

```
PERL_UNICODE=LADS rename -n 's|^\./.{10}\K.*\.doc\z|.test.doc\z|s' ./*.doc
```

(beware that contrary to `zmv`, it will not guard against several files mapping to the same file)

If you don't have any of these, with a POSIX-like shell like FreeBSD's `/bin/sh`:

```
for file in ??????????*.doc; do
  newfile=${file%"${file#??????????}"}.test.doc
  echo mv -i -- "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

(remove `echo` when happy).

With any Bourne-like shell:

```
for file in ??????????*.doc; do
  newfile=`expr " $file" : ' \(.\{10\}\)'`.test.doc
  echo mv -i -- "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thanks for the reply.. I should learn zmv better it seems.

Answer (score 3):

a simple for loop in shell with a bit of `sed`:

```
for file in *
do
echo mv "$file" `echo "$file" | sed -e 's/\(.\{10\}\).*.\(.\{3\}\)/\1.test.\2/'`
done
```

if you are happy with the output get rid of the `echo` before `mv`.

This will process all the files in the directory and will work for filenames with three characters long extension.

Comment: (assuming file names don't contain space, tab, newline, wildcard, possibly  backslash characters and don't start with `-`; also note that the `.` in `\(.\{3\}\)` matches any character, not just `.`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions, some depending on the OS:

```
Rename multiple files, groups of files

        1) rename -- Debian version and RedHat version differ, q.v.
           (try package util-linux:
           http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux)

        2) ren -- RedHat relatives

        3) renameutils -- package contains qmv, imv, icp, qcp, and deurlname

        4) mved -- (circa 2006; good as of 2015.05), perl
           http://raf.org/mved/
           (An earlier shell version may be available.)

        5) rename -- perl builtin library routine (DIY)

        6) mmv -- move/rename/copy/append/link multiple files by wildcard patterns

        7) gprename - batch rename using a GUI

        8) krename - batch rename using a GUI
```

For example, this code in file s1 demonstrates mved:

```
# Set up environment.
pl " Input data file of names $FILE:"
head $FILE


i=0
while IFS='' read -r file
do
  (( i++ ))
  # echo " Name $i: $file"
  touch "$file"
done < $FILE

pl " Files to consider renaming:"
ls -1 *.doc

pl " Expected output:"
cat $E

# "Order21039 Internal Document.doc" -> "Order21039.test.doc"
pl " Verbose execution and file list:"
mved -v "??????????*.doc" ==========.test.doc
pe
ls -1 *.doc
```

produces:

```
 Input data file of names data1:
Order21039 Internal Document.doc
Order33920 New Order.doc
Order39307 Exam.doc

-----
 Files to consider renaming:
Order21039 Internal Document.doc
Order33920 New Order.doc
Order39307 Exam.doc

-----
 Expected output:
Order21039.test.doc
Order33920.test.doc
Order39307.test.doc

-----
 Verbose execution and file list:
mv Order21039 Internal Document.doc Order21039.test.doc
mv Order33920 New Order.doc Order33920.test.doc
mv Order39307 Exam.doc Order39307.test.doc

Order21039.test.doc
Order33920.test.doc
Order39307.test.doc
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: FreeBSD, 11.0-RELEASE-p9, amd64
bash GNU bash 4.4.12
```

Some details for (perl) code mved:

```
mved    carefully rename multiple files (man)
Path    : ~/bin/mved
Version : 1.4
Length  : 495 lines
Type    : Perl script, ASCII text executable
Shebang : #!/usr/bin/env perl
Help    : probably available with -h
Home    : http://raf.org/mved/ (doc)
Modules : (for perl codes)
 warnings       1.23
 strict 1.08
 Getopt::Std    1.10
```

The calling sequence for mved includes a local "wildcard", "=", that stands for the corresponding result of the wildcard match in the first expression.

cheers, drl

Comment: Sorry, but correct me if I'm wrong.. Wouldn't "rm -f *.doc" deletes all my document files before renaming them?!?

Comment: Yes. This is a demo, so I wanted to clear out all of MY clutter.  Apologies for the confusion, and thanks for pointing this out ... cheers, drl

Comment: @terdon -- thanks for taking care of that edit ... cheers,